# Identify person who completed a Collect Data task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, tasks

I'm using "Collect Data From User" in a workflow to issue a task to a group. I need to be able to identify the member of the group who completed the task. The current solution is a People field in the Collect Data dialog, where the person who completes the task has to select their own name, even though they are already logged-in - this is extremely redundant and inefficient.

For a workflow attached to changes to tasks, the following just returns "System Account", as the system updates the status of the task before I can gain access to it...

```
[%Current Item:Modified By%]
```

A solution would be to access the "Modified By" field for the previous revision of the task, but I'm not aware of a way to achieve this from a workflow.

The following doesn't work either, as the current user is whoever created the list item that initiated the workflow...

```
[%Workflow Context:Current User%]
```

A workaround would be to use [Me] as the default for the People field in the dialog box, but People fields do not allow for defaults.

Is there any way of finding who approved a task by using a Sharepoint workflow? The workflow is created in Sharepoint Designer 2010.

Answer (score 2):

The Collect Data From User action outputs a list item ID as a variable. This is the item id of the task. You can use that variable to look up to the task list who modified the task item.